# CMake 3.16.x not building gRPC 1.23/1.26 anymore on Windows 10 (VS 2017)

Tags: cmake, grpc

My team and I are building gRPC using CMake. We have been building gRPC v1.26 (and v1.23 too) just fine with CMake 3.15.6, but since CMake 3.16.x is not building anymore.
This is the log of the tools we are using:

```
[29/32 0.2/sec] Performing configure step for 'grpc'
loading initial cache file C:/TCSoftware/build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug/_deps/grpc_src-build/grpc/tmp/grpc-cache-Debug.cmake
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27034.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27034.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Protobuf: C:/TCSoftware/build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug/install/external/lib/libprotobufd.lib (found version "3.8.0") 
-- Found OpenSSL: optimized;C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MD.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MDd.lib (found version "1.1.1d")  
-- Found ZLIB: C:/TCSoftware/build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug/install/external/lib/zlibd.lib (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/TCSoftware/build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug/_deps/grpc_src-build/grpc/src/grpc-build
```

After configure step, something fails in the build step. However as it can be seen the building process does *not* stop.

```
[30/32 0.1/sec] Performing build step for 'grpc'
FAILED: C:/TCSoftware/build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug/_deps/grpc_src-build/grpc/src/grpc-stamp/grpc-build 
cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\_deps\grpc_src-build\grpc\src\grpc-build && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E touch C:/TCSoftware/build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug/_deps/grpc_src-build/grpc/src/grpc-stamp/grpc-build"
[1/1580 1.3/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\grpc_cronet.dir\src\core\lib\iomgr\udp_server.cc.obj
[2/1580 2.5/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\grpc_cronet.dir\src\core\lib\iomgr\timer_heap.cc.obj
[3/1580 3.3/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\grpc_cronet.dir\src\core\lib\iomgr\timer.cc.obj
```

It builds a lot of objects until it starts showing strange warnings as follows, but it still keeps building.

```
[975/1580 5.8/sec] Linking CXX static library gpr.lib
[976/1580 5.8/sec] Linking C static library address_sorting.lib
[977/1580 5.8/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\grpc.dir\src\core\lib\backoff\backoff.cc.obj
...
[982/1580 5.8/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\grpc_ruby_plugin.dir\src\compiler\ruby_plugin.cc.obj
C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\include\google/protobuf/stubs/logging.h(102): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::message_': class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xstring(4373): note: see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\include\google/protobuf/arena_impl.h(251): warning C4251: 'google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::lifecycle_id_generator_': struct 'std::atomic<__int64>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xxatomic(162): note: see declaration of 'std::atomic<__int64>'
```

More warnings are shown as follows:

```
[1531/1580 5.5/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\grpc_print_google_default_creds_token.dir\test\core\security\print_google_default_creds_token.cc.obj
[1532/1580 5.5/sec] Linking CXX static library grpc++.lib
server_posix.cc.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
rpc_method.cc.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
create_channel_posix.cc.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
[1533/1580 5.5/sec] Linking CXX static library grpc_plugin_support.lib
[1534/1580 5.5/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\grpc_create_jwt.dir\test\core\security\create_jwt.cc.obj
[1535/1580 5.5/sec] Linking CXX static library grpc++_unsecure.lib
server_posix.cc.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
rpc_method.cc.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
create_channel_posix.cc.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
[1536/1580 5.5/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\grpc_create_jwt.dir\test\core\util\cmdline.cc.obj
[1537/1580 5.5/sec] Linking CXX executable grpc_ruby_plugin.exe
FAILED: grpc_ruby_plugin.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\grpc_ruby_plugin.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100177~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100177~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\grpc_ruby_plugin.dir\src\compiler\ruby_plugin.cc.obj  /out:grpc_ruby_plugin.exe /implib:grpc_ruby_plugin.lib /pdb:grpc_ruby_plugin.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\lib\libprotocd.lib  C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\lib\libprotobufd.lib  grpc_plugin_support.lib  C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\lib\libprotocd.lib  C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\lib\libprotobufd.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\grpc_ruby_plugin.dir\src\compiler\ruby_plugin.cc.obj /out:grpc_ruby_plugin.exe /implib:grpc_ruby_plugin.lib /pdb:grpc_ruby_plugin.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\lib\libprotocd.lib C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\lib\libprotobufd.lib grpc_plugin_support.lib C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\lib\libprotocd.lib C:\TCSoftware\build-frontend-Qt5132_MSVC17_cmake-Debug\install\external\lib\libprotobufd.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\grpc_ruby_plugin.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\grpc_ruby_plugin.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
ruby_plugin.cc.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ?name@FileDescriptor@protobuf@google@@QEBAAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ (public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const & __cdecl google::protobuf::FileDescriptor::name(void)const ) imported in function "bool __cdecl grpc_ruby_generator::ServicesFilename(class google::protobuf::FileDescriptor const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *)" (?ServicesFilename@grpc_ruby_generator@@YA_NPEBVFileDescriptor@protobuf@google@@PEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
grpc_plugin_support.lib(ruby_generator.cc.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ?name@FileDescriptor@protobuf@google@@QEBAAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ (public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const & __cdecl google::protobuf::FileDescriptor::name(void)const ) imported
ruby_plugin.cc.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??0CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@QEAA@PEAVZeroCopyOutputStream@123@@Z (public: __cdecl google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::CodedOutputStream(class google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream *)) imported in function "public: virtual bool __cdecl RubyGrpcGenerator::Generate(class google::protobuf::FileDescriptor const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class google::protobuf::compiler::GeneratorContext *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *)const " (?Generate@RubyGrpcGenerator@@UEBA_NPEBVFileDescriptor@protobuf@google@@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PEAVGeneratorContext@compiler@34@PEAV56@@Z)
```

Build stops after a lot of the above warnings with the following log:

```
ruby_plugin.cc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: 
__cdecl google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGenerator::CodeGenerator(void)" (__imp_??0CodeGenerator@compiler@protobuf@google@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl RubyGrpcGenerator::RubyGrpcGenerator(void)" (??0RubyGrpcGenerator@@QEAA@XZ)
ruby_plugin.cc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl google::protobuf::compiler::PluginMain(int,char * * const,class google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGenerator const *)" (__imp_?PluginMain@compiler@protobuf@google@@YAHHQEAPEADPEBVCodeGenerator@123@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl grpc::protobuf::compiler::PluginMain(int,char * * const,class google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGenerator const *)" (?PluginMain@compiler@protobuf@grpc@@YAHHQEAPEADPEBVCodeGenerator@12google@@@Z)
grpc_plugin_support.lib(ruby_generator.cc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const & __cdecl google::protobuf::Descriptor::name(void)const " (__imp_?name@Descriptor@protobuf@google@@QEBAAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl grpc_ruby_generator::RubyTypeOf(class google::protobuf::Descriptor const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?RubyTypeOf@grpc_ruby_generator@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PEBVDescriptor@protobuf@google@@AEBV23@@Z)
```

The only thing changed between working build and not working one is: removing build folder, uninstall CMake 3.15.x, reboot, install CMake 3.16.0, build grpc all over again.

Anyone faced something like this? Thank you

Comment: If you keep seeing the problem, please files as an issue under https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/